# Error on Querytable Refresh

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I have recently been upgraded to excel 2016.

I run a process which refreshes a query that is querying an access database.

In 2010 the process works without any issues, 
but in 2016 I get the error

> Run-time error '-2147417848(80010108)':  Mehtod 'refresh of oject
>   '_queryTable' failed

on this line

```
Sheets("database").range("A1").listoject.querytable.refresh
```

I have tried

```
Dim BigQry As QueryTable
Set BigQry = Sheets("database").Range("A1").ListObject.QueryTable
BigQry.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

As well as

```
Dim tbl as listobject
set tbl = sheets("database").listobjects("tableX")
Tbl.refresh
```

Does any one know why the excel version would be doing this? I have tested on 3 different users now, same result

Comment: The error line has a misspelling. Do you have `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your module?

Comment: The spelling is correct in the file, I typed it out manually for the post

Comment: OK.  Have you tried recording a macro to do the Refresh and seeing what code is generated?

Comment: Hi, I recorded refreshing the query. the query refreshes, but the macro recorder does not record anything. I think the spreadsheet must be corrupt because as soon as any macro is running I am unable to debug and move around the workbook. I recorded a macro just selecting different sheets ect.. and only sheets which do not contain query tables are selected. This is the case in 2010 and 2016

Comment: That is unfortunate.  But if the query refreshes when done manually, but not programmatically, perhaps there is a timing issue having to do with availability of the data source.  Maybe if you `Wait` a few or ten seconds, the refresh can be done programmatically. (I've had that happen fetching data from web pages, although not with queries).

Comment: Cheers for the attempt very strang indeed, I'm going to replicate the situation in another workbook. I'll let you know how I get on